# How to style button using relative CSS units?

Tags: html, css

There is design in figma of button with properties:

```
fontsize: 13px
fontweight: bold
```

I try to style it using relative units like `em, rem`.
Is it proper way to use em for paddig for font-size and rem for padding? Because padding depends of button's font-size.

How to convert fontsize 13px to em?
And should I use padding for text of button container?

```
<button>
   <span>Search</span>
</button>
```

As I know to use `em` I have to specify `font-size` for parent element in `px`.
Could you explain please how to stylish it correctly?

My attemptions is:

```
button {
    background: #E30513;
    color: white;
    font-size: 0.8125rem; // it is 13px like in design based 16px of body
    padding: 1em; // relative parent's font size
    border:none;
    border-radius:0.625em; relative parent's font size
}
```

Comment: Percent depends on its parent font size. EM is relative to the current font size of the element (2em means 2 times the size of the current font). So, If the font size of body is 16 pixels, then 150% will be 24 pixels (1.5 * 16), and 2em will be 32 pixels (16 * 2).

Comment: em is relative to closest parent? ot to body? Should I set font-size for button in 13px like in design and use padding in em?

Comment: Try to look at the bigger picture. Always keep font size in rem. Padding may or not be done in em. Suppose you put padding as 1em. Then later if u need the padding to grow or shrink with the font size, em is the way to go as padding depends on font size of the button. However, if u need a fixed padding, rem is the way. Also, u don't need a span to wrap the text

Comment: I still can not get about font-size. In design it is in pixels. What to use? For padding I got, i is in em, because I have to scale padding depends font-size of parent.

Comment: For example to use fontsize 13px in rem it is `0.8125rem`. Then padding is in em?

Comment: See my updationg please

Comment: Go ahead with rem. It's better for accessibility. Yes 13px is 0.8125rem by default px size which is 16. If u change the root to 10px it becomes 1.3rem. 1 em means whatever the px value of font size relative to that. So 1em is 13px for padding if font size is 13px for the button.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really good at explaining but I hope this makes sense.

You could first set the `html` `font-size` to `10px` now the is the root element font size,then the `body` to be `1.6rem` which means `16px` and now whenever you want to set the font size for any element with relative pixels to the root.

for example the button font-size `13px` you could set it to `1.3rem`

when it comes to `padding` and `border-radius` use `em` becasue it's relative to the current element font-size, so `padding:1em;` means `13px`

```css
html{
  font-size:10px; /*   1rem = 10px */ 
}

body{
  font-size:1.6rem;/*   1.6*10 =16px*/
}

button{
    background: #E30513;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    font-size:1.3rem; /*1.3*10 = 13px */  
    padding:1em; /*   1*13 = 13px */
    border:none;
    border-radius:1em; /*   0.6*13 = 7.8px */
}
```

```html
<div>
<button>
   <span>Search</span>
</button>
</div>
```